# Pass a C++ struct pointer from one class to another one

Tags: c++

I've two different classes (class1 class2) both of them have their own header and cpp files. Class2 has included the header of class1. Class1 has two structures which are public. 
I want to call a method from class2 in class1 and to pass two pointers pointing on the structures.

The call of the method from class2 in class1. (obj is an object of class2 in class1):

```
obj.routine(ip_s.c_str(), &NLP_data_recv, &recv_data_data); //write to harddrive
```

Following the declaration of the method in class2:

```
int routine(std::string raw_data_re, struct NLP_data_header_package *Header_data, struct NLP_data_data_package *Data_data);
```

The following Error occurs:

```
 “argument of type ""com::NLP_data_data_package *"" is incompatible with    parameter of type ""NLP_data_data_package *""
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

EDIT: Additional code:

class com header(class1):

```
#ifndef COM_H 
#define COM_H 
//... 
#include "Dateiverwaltung.h" 
//... 

class com 
{ 
private: 

Dateiverwaltung obj; 
//... 
public: 

int run(void); 
com(std::array<std::string,TWO> socket); 
~com(); 

struct NLP_data_header_package 
{ 
//... 
}NLP_data_recv; 

struct NLP_data_data_package 
{ 
//... 
}recv_data_data;
```

class com cpp (class1)

```
//... 
if (recv_command == DATA_COMMAND) 
     { 
         obj.routine(ip_s.c_str(), &NLP_data_recv, &recv_data_data); //write to harddrive 
         obj.ext_close_file(); 
     } 
//...
```

class Dateiverwaltung header(class2)

```
#ifndef DATEIVERWALTUNG_H 
#define DATEIVERWALTUNG_H 

//... 
#include "communication.h" 
//... 
public: 
Dateiverwaltung(char* directory_global_re); 
~Dateiverwaltung();   

 int routine(std::string raw_data_re, struct NLP_data_header_package *Header_data, struct NLP_data_data_package *Data_data); 
 int ext_close_file(void); 
//...
```

class Dateiverwaltung cpp (class2)

```
//... 
int Dateiverwaltung::routine(string raw_data_re, struct NLP_data_header_package *Header_data, struct NLP_data_data_package *Data_data) 
{ 
//...
```

Comment: Outside of the class `com`, the struct defined inside it is called `com::NLP_data_data_package`, and `struct NLP_data_data_package` refers to a different type (one which you haven't defined). And C++ doesn't need "struct"-warts on structure types, you can just use the name itself.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work that way. I get the following error message: error c2653 "com" is not a class or namespace name. Well actually it is a class but it doesn't work though.

Comment: Do you happen to have two definitions of the struct called "NLP_data_data_package", in two different places? I think this question needs more code and less prose.

Comment: No I've just one definition, just checked it with strg+f in all files

Comment: Remove "struct" from the parameters and you'll probably get a more informative error message,

Comment: If I understand the code correctly I'm pretty sure that what you are trying to achieve will not work because both headers are dependent on each other. You need to break up the dependencies using forward declarations or a separate header / namespace for your structs. This is probably not the cause for your compilation error but what's ahead of you once you fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

The error says there's a "com::NLP_data_data_package"
and a "NLP_data_data_package"

That's two different classes (for the compiler), since they seem to be defined in different namespaces, namely com and the default namespace.

Comment: The structure NLP_data_data_package is defined in the first class (class com) but after passing it as a pointer to class two I get this error message. I don't understand how to solve this problem.