# C++ pass struct from from one class to another class

Tags: c++, class, struct, arguments

I have two classes A and B defined in A.h, A.cpp and B.h, B.cpp respectively. Class A has a structure that I want to use in a function of Class B. Because Class B is included in Class A, I can't  include class A in Class B as it will lead to circular dependency. Code for all the files are given below:
A.h

```
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H
#include B.h
namespace common {
    class A {
    public:
        static struct strctOfA {
           float p1 = 2;
        } structA;
        void functionOfA();
    };
}
#endif // !_A_H
```

A.cpp

```
#include A.h
using namespace common;
A::functionOfA() {
    B b;
    b.functionOfB(structA);
}
```

B.h

```
#ifndef _B_H
#define _B_H
namespace common {
    class B {
    public:
         functionOfB(??);
    };
}
#endif // !_B_H
```

B.cpp

```
#include B.h
using namespace common;
B::functionOfB(??) {
        // Want to use structA here;        
}
```

I looked into StackOverflow and found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564322/pass-a-c-struct-pointer-from-one-class-to-another-one) quite close to my problem, however, they it either doesn't explains the answer or I am not able to understand their solution. Please help me with this.

Thanks

**Update**
Thanks I-V for pointing out the mistake and providing me the explanation. Updating the code worked for me. Thanks everyone for providing additional knowledge to my C/C++ coding skills. :)

Comment: your `#include` syntax is questionable. Are these really your source files?

Comment: This really isn't that hard. Use include guards, and include the header files for classes that you care about.

Comment: Hey Marcus, I have create a similar scenario of my code. 

@JonathonReinhart: can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: You haven't presented a real problem. You've just said "will lead to circular dependency". Are you experiencing any compile-time or run-time errors? If so, please be explicit and ask about those problems.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: But I don't want cyclic dependencies in the code due to header files.

Comment: @MilanJain Then you need to re-design your code. Otherwise, accept what I've indicated, use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), and move on.

Comment: @MilanJain *But I don't want cyclic dependencies in the code due to header files.*  They don't create a cyclic dependency.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: So, I guess you mean we aren't allowed to pass struct from class A (including class B) to another class B until and unless we don't use cyclic dependency?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Is A.h including B.h and B.h including A.h fine?

Comment: @MilanJain. As mentioned, you should ALWAYS use include guards, implicit dependencies can arise which may cause inclusion of files that you hadn't designed for. Include guards would mitigate any further duplications of objects, I can't think of a reason NOT to use them other than lazy-ness. Keep the code portable by using #ifndef rather than #pragma which is windows.

Comment: @lfgtm: I am actually using the include guards, however forgot to mention in the code. I am sorry about that. I have updated the code. The thing I was not able to understand was including A.h in B.h and B.h in A.h, which I feel is a cyclic inclusion.

Comment: @MilanJain, It is a cyclic inclusion as you correctly assume, however what is important is what is being included. If you include code in a header, then that will get re-included (duplicated) and isn't very good, code should be kept to source (.cpp)  files (there are a few behavior caveats such as inlining etc with puttng code in the header) which I won't discuss here. Use mainly forward declarations and function prototypes in headers.

Comment: @MilanJain. By using a forward declaration, all c++ compiler will know is the fact that the struct/class simply exist (declared) and does not need to know anything about it (defined) until later in the compilation/linking process. To stop a function being circularly included you could also make it static which equates to it existing ONCE in the compiled code (despite being part of a 'cyclic inclusion').

Comment: @lfgtm: That information is really helpful. Thanks for sharing man :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, what you wrote is a bad habit.

There is no reason to include B.h in A.h because you don't use any part of B.h in the A.h file. A better way to implement it is to include B.h in A.cpp and not in the header file.

It will also solve the cycle of includes you have..

In general, it is recommended to include files in .cpp file and NOT in header files when you don't use functions/objects of the included file in the header file :)

In addition, you should use #pragma once for Windows or ifndef for anything else in order to be safe of conflicts

A.h

```
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H
namespace common {
    class A {
    public:
        static struct strctOfA {
           float p1 = 2;
        } structA;
    }
}
#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include A.h
#include B.h
using namespace common;
class A {
    B b;
    b.functionOfB(structA);
}
```

NOTE: from B.cpp include A.h

Comment: I included B.h to call its function. You will check that in A.cpp. However, thanks for the advice in later part. I didn't know about that.

Comment: But you must not implement anything in header file! How could you call a function in A.h??

Comment: You are welcome :) the only exception is when using templates... then you implement in the header file but then the compilation and linking are different

Comment: Great! Thanks Man :)

Comment: "But you must not implement anything in header file! " Implementing in a header generally should be avoided, but "must not" is too strong a wording. Take templates for example. They very often need to be implemented in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with forward-declarations, unless you abolutely must pass it by value. But I can't think of a scenario where this wouldn't work with references.

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

struct B;
struct A {void f(B&);};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
void A::f(B & value) {/* do something */ };
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_


struct A;
struct B {void f(B&);};

#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
void B::f(A & value) {/* do something */ };
```

If you need to have a value of B in A with only a forward-declaration you can put it in a pointer, i.e. use a std::unique_ptr.